# Riffle shuffle algorithm with randomness

Tags: algorithm, random

The riffle shuffle algorithm is too mechanical and predictable. How would we add some randomness as if a real human was shuffling the cards but still using the riffle method?

Comment: Try the [Fisher-Yates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) shuffling algorithm.

Comment: Could you detail what *you* mean by "the riffle shuffle algorithm", as there are certainly variations of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the paper *Shuffling Cards and Stopping Times* by Aldous and Diaconis (from the American Mathematical Monthly, **93**:5, pp 333-348) the authors looked at how many shuffles are required to randomise a deck of cards.  Section 4 of that paper is *An Analysis of Riffle Shuffles* and they discuss some equivalent formulations for (non-perfect) riffling of cards.

In particular, they quote a model for random riffling shuffling that simulates how "real" people riffle shuffle.  Essentially, the deck is split in to two pieces according to a binomial distribution, leaving `c` cards in one hand and `n-c` in the other.  The cards are then *"dropped from a given hand with probability proportional to packet size"*.

So a simple application will be to assume that your deck is originally split in to two equal pieces and then repeatedly select from which piece the next card comes, with `a / (a+b)` probability of it coming from the piece of size `a` and `b / (a+b)` probability of the piece of current size `b`.